# Swift: Auto Layout - programatically adding a pop-up view

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, subview, safearealayoutguide

I'm generating a `KeyboardView` that slides up vertically and then occupies the bottom 1/3 of a view that is used to generate it:

```
class KeyboardView: UIView {

    private var width: CGFloat!
    private var height: CGFloat!

    init(withinView view: UIView) {
        super.init(frame: view.frame)
        configureKeyboard()
    }

    private func configureKeyboard() {
        width = frame.width
        height = frame.height * 0.33
        center = CGPoint(x: width / 2, y: frame.height - halfHeight)
        let origin = CGPoint(x: center.x - halfWidth, y: (center.y - halfHeight) + height)
        let size = CGSize(width: width, height: height)
        frame = CGRect(origin: origin, size: size)    
        isUserInteractionEnabled = true

    }

}
```

I then add the keys of this keyboard as `UIButton` instances after the `configureKeyboard` method has been called.

**However**, when running this code on, say, an iPhoneX the keys of this keyboard are not within the so-called safe area of the iPhone screen.

Should I be adjusting the `frame.origin` value to accommodate the bottom inset? i.e.

```
frame.origin.y += UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.safeAreaInsets.bottom ?? 0.0
```

or is there another way to achieve this programatically?

Thanks for any help, still adjusting to using auto layout.

Comment: What is the goal here? There is a right way to make a custom keyboard and this is not it.

Comment: @matt To make a custom numerical keyboard as a pop-up view. The implementation works well, but I'm wondering about the autolayout issues ... Thanks.

Comment: Ok but as I say this is not how to make a custom numerical keyboard. You need an input view.

Comment: @matt I have delegate methods for this `KeyboardView` class that communicate to a `UILabel`. Is this what you mean by an input view?

Comment: @matt Any views on the auto layout question, please? Thanks

Comment: " this what you mean by an input view?" No, I mean an input view: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiinputview. If you used this, you'd get a true custom keyboard presented by the system in the correct way. — Would it help you to see an example? I have an example here of a UIPickerView connected to a UILabel, much like what you seem to want to do: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/a23f4ae7a2970be47069ca6d3117d39fa03e7644/bk2ch10p525InputViewTest2/InputViewTest/ViewController.swift